# how to replace array values in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays

I would like to be able to read all my array values, from input array string as the following below:

**input string**

value1, value2

**Desired Output:**

value1, title like '% value2 %',

My current function outputting all the results, in once line and not including `"%' OR TITLE LIKE '%"`.  How can I achieve this?

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
  string[] test = { "value1", "value2", "value3" };

  string resultString = string.Empty;
  Array.ForEach(test, e => resultString += e.Replace(",", "%' OR TITLE LIKE '%"));

  Console.WriteLine( "Result is: " + resultString);

  Console.ReadLine();
  }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Your question is unclear. What is the expected result from your sample array? Btw, `Array.ForEach` takes an array as first parameter not an int.

Comment: the function above outputs data: `result is value1value2value3`, whereas I would like to know, how I can the desired output, as stated in my post above. thanks

Comment: Not clear, why am I getting negative ratings on this post?

Comment: Because your question is unclear and confusing. The code that you've shown is different to what you ask. You say that input-string is `"value1, value2"` but the code uses a `string[]`. Then you've provided code that does not even compile (now fixed). Then you r desired output is unclear, is that a string literal `"value1, title like '% value2 %',"`? If not, show the actual  desired output.

Comment: Apology to cause confusion on your end, on side note english is not really my first language.  however, i would like my output to be like the `desired output`, as illustrated above.

Comment: Then i don't understand it at all. Why is `"value1, title like '% value2 %',"` the desired output, what algorithm could yield that from your three strings? Why doesn't it include the `OR` from your code in  `"%' OR TITLE LIKE '%"`? Why do you replace commas, there are no commas in the strings in the array.  And why do you complain because it outputs all in one line? How do you want to output that single string instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably this is what you are expecting?

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      string[] test = { "value1", "value2", "value3" };

      string resultString = string.Empty;

      foreach (String s in test)
      {
          resultString += String.Format("%'{0}'%, ", s);
      }

      Console.WriteLine(resultString);
      Console.ReadLine();         
    }
```

The result it produces is : %'value1'%, %'value2'%, %'value3'%,

Answer (score 0):

you can use Array.IndexOf to find it:

```
arr[Array.IndexOf(arr, "Value5")] = "value1";
```

something like this loops internally:

```
string[] test = { "value1", "value2", "value3" };

string[] test = items.Select(x => x.Replace("value1", "zero")).ToArray();
```

Comment: Ideally I would first check that "IndexOf" does not return a negative value

Comment: @NoelWidmer Array index starts from zero it will not return negative index

Comment: thanks for your solution, but my input array string is dynamically generated, so I am little unsure, how can define int array index to my function, instead of specifying the string value? Any second element in the array, should be outputted as shown in the desired output above. Thanks

Comment: @MidhunMundayadan It WILL return -1 if the specified key DOES NOT exist an thus can throw an IndexOutOfRangeException if you do not check that